# Remote Desktop not working with Intel Arc

Tags: remote-desktop

I used the bultin RDP from windows to Ubuntu 23.04 with an NVIDIA gpu and I just swapped over for the time being to an Intel Arc A380

When I try to RDP in I just get a black screen the 1st time, after that it just does not work.

Where might the issues be so I can report to the correct maintainers?

My kernel version is 6.2.0-24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I removed the nvidia packages, I assume there some conflict even though since there is no hardware nothing is needed from driver.